# Как в jquery реализован доступ к $, как к функции и как к объекту

Tags: jquery, ооп, javascript

Здравствуйте, начал изучать js более глубоко и пробовать делать свои велосипеды, чтобы закрепить материал. Поставил задачу сделать что-то вроде jquery, с ограниченным ф-налом, и столкнулся с проблемой.
Вот код который я набросал: http://jsfiddle.net/5b3Hv/

Строчка 40, ajax вызывается нормально, так как обращение происходит через ();
Строчка 41, возвращается ошибка, так как я пытаюсь обратиться к функции как к объекту и у текущей функции нет метода ajax.

Собственно цель сделать так, чтобы можно было обращаться через $.() и $();
Что поправить в архитектуре чтобы это было возможно?)

Comment: немного теории - в js функция и есть объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax = function(){console.log('x');};
$.ajax();
```

> можно было обращаться через $.()

Это как? Обращаться к замыканию объекта?

upd

> как это организовано в jQuery

[через extend](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#l382)

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно расширить ф-цию controllerJquery методом ajax.
Спасибо )